# php preg_replace mysql datetime or time or date in json string to timestamp

Tags: php, regex, json, datetime, preg-replace

I'm trying to prepare data to send as json in a restful server, so i need to prepare data so that all dates be converted to unix timestamp and all numric values are not surrounded by double quotes.

my current attempt is

```
$j = json_encode($data); //json_encode($data,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
$j = preg_replace('/(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})/e', "strtotime('$1')", $j);//timedate
$j = preg_replace('/(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})/e', "strtotime('$1')", $j);//dates
$j = preg_replace('/(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})/e', "strtotime('$1')", $j);//time
$j = preg_replace('/\"([0-9]+)\",/', "$1,",$j);//remove double quotes from around int values

echo $j;
```

but i'm kinda worried that this might backfire (bug), is this universal approach considered safe ? is there a better/faster way to do it ?

Comment: `/e` is deprecated, use preg_replace_callback instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Bad. `/e` modifier is

## ***BAD!!!!!***

Instead, try this:

```
$j = preg_replace_callback(
    '/"(\d{4}-\d-\d \d\d:\d\d:\d\d)"/',
    function($m) {return strtotime($m[1]);},
    $j
);
```

This uses the correct method for dynamic callback-based regex replacements, and condenses your steps into one.

Answer (score 0):

Well you could modify it before encoding to JSON, avoiding the regex overhead, and catching strings that look like dates but are not.

Just iterate recursively over the data structure, and convert to a timestamp anything that's a DateTime object or the like. Then just encode it to JSON.

As for the numbers, cast them to integers or floats.